# Get position of div in relation to other divs

Tags: jquery

I have grid of divs 3 x 3

When i drag an item and it is dropped I would like to know the position of the dropped div in relation 
to all of the other divs.

Should I set an X,Y value on each div, and when it is dropped access the X,Y value of the div being moved ?

As showed in http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/8LQmE/ I would like to get the X,Y position of the div being dropped in
relation to the other divs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method that calculates and returns the pixel coordinates of the given element, relative to the document.

To get the position of one element relative to another, calculate the difference of the positions of the two elements:

```
var d1 = $("#div1");
var d2 = $("#div2");
var p1 = d1.offset();
var p2 = d2.offset();
var rel = { left: p2.left-p1.left, top: p2.top-p1.top };
```

Comment: Does that work if I need to access the position of the div relative to another div, so instead of returning the offset if an item is dragged to poistion 0,0 in relation to other divs, the position 0,0 will be returned ?